# streamlit Authenticate login giving error

Tags: python, streamlit

I have and app on streamlit. Because it is public, I ensure its security by using a simple login screen. It has been working without any problems for about 2 months. It started giving errors for a few days even though I didn't touch anything. That's why I couldn't understand what caused the error.

Code:

```
def Login():

    authenticator = Authenticate(
            config['credentials'],
            config['cookie']['name'],
            config['cookie']['key'],
            config['cookie']['expiry_days'],
            config['preauthorized']
        )
    global name, authentication_status, username 
    name, authentication_status, username = authenticator.login('Login', 'main')
    if authentication_status:
        st.title('title of page')
        AfterLoginConfig()
        AfterLoginTopMenu()
        AfterLogin()
    elif authentication_status == False:
        st.error('Username/password is incorrect')
    elif authentication_status == None:
        st.warning('Please enter your username and password')
```

The error:

```
File "/mount/src/enerji-takip/streamlit_app.py", line 1059, in Login
    name, authentication_status, username = authenticator.login('Login', 'main')
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit_authenticator/authenticate.py", line 238, in login
    raise DeprecationError("""Likely deprecation error, the 'form_name' parameter has been replaced with the 'fields' parameter. For further information please refer to                                    https://github.com/mkhorasani/Streamlit-Authenticator/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#authenticatelogin""")

[The file that rises error](https://github.com/mkhorasani/Streamlit-Authenticator/blob/main/streamlit_authenticator/authenticate.py)
```

I tried several things like chance parameters but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

The login function has changed on streamlit_authenticator.

Instead of:

```
authenticator.login('custom_form_name', 'main')
```

Use:

```
authenticator.login('main', fields = {'Form name': 'custom_form_name'})
```

Hope this hepls.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when using the tutorial available on streamlit.
However, the method definition seems to now be:

```
    def login(self, location: str='main', max_concurrent_users: Optional[int]=None, fields: dict={'Form name':'Login', 
                                                                                              'Username':'Username', 
                                                                                              'Password':'Password',
                                                                                              'Login':'Login'}) -> tuple:
    """
    Creates a login widget.

    Parameters
    ----------
    location: str
        The location of the login widget i.e. main or sidebar.
    max_concurrent_users: int
        The number of maximum users allowed to login concurrently.
    fields: dict
        The rendered names of the fields/buttons.
```

So just try changing

```
name, authentication_status, username = authenticator.login('Login', 'main')
```

to

```
name, authentication_status, username = authenticator.login('main')
```

It worked for me